# postgresQL extension functions in C (any changes from v8.0x to v9.0)?

Tags: c, postgresql

I wrote a C extension library for postgreSQL several years ago, way back when version 8.0 was the new kid on the block.

I am using Version1 calling conventions - which according to the [postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/xfunc-c.html), is still the way to extend postgreSQl.

I want to know however, if there are any gotchas I need to know before loading my 'old' shared libraries into the v9.01 database.?

Answer (score 1):

No material changes. Your SO's should work as-is.